# How can I run a separate layout for Tabs in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, kotlin

I created a separate layout for tablets in android studio, but I'm unable to run that particular layout, whenever I try to run it, it default runs the normal layout, which is for mobile

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We would love to help you, but there are some problems in the current format/content of your question that makes it hard for some of us to help. If you haven't done so already, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so it will be easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with the user Ricardo but having said that, I need some more information. First of all how you load the layout, what is the layout name and where did you place these layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Check this before https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html and you have to do something like this.
  In your manifest

```
<resources>
    <bool name="isTablet">true</bool>
</resources>

<resources>
    <bool name="isTablet">false</bool>
</resources>
```

In your Mainactivity

```
boolean tabletSize = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet);
    if (tabletSize) {
        // do something
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
```